# In order to know jQuery, do I have to know JavaScript first?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In order to know jQuery, do I have to know JavaScript first?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My answer is also **YES** and Here are the reasons in this nice article:

[**Learning Javascript or Simply the JS Frameworks?**](http://www.thewebsqueeze.com/web-design-articles/learning-javascript-or-simply-the-js-frameworks.html)

Quoting main reasons from above article:

- **Frameworks don’t do it all.**

> Whereas frameworks and code libraries
>   often take a lot of the heavy lifting
>   when coding up sites, they can’t do it
>   all. If you come along and think “I
>   need to do this” and your framework
>   does not provide such a function,
>   you’re stuck up a creek without one
>   very handy paddle.

- **Employment**

> Imagine you’ve spent 9 years working
>   with jQuery but never took the time,
>   for whatever reason, to fully learn
>   Javascript. Then you see the perfect
>   job vacancy, javascript developer at a
>   well respected company with very good
>   pay. You’re thinking to yourself that
>   they HAVE to pick you, you’ve worked
>   with javascript for so long, but when
>   you arrive and they ask you about your
>   knowledge of javascript, you’re in
>   trouble.

- **Easier to pick up the framework**

> If you’ve spent a period of time with
>   javascript, the syntax that jQuery
>   (and most other javascript frameworks)
>   uses is going to be a lot easier to
>   pick up and a lot easier to master.

- **Edit the Source and Plug In!**

> It’s always great fun to dive into the
>   code and edit the library to suit
>   yourself, you can add your own
>   functions when you find a gap in the
>   library

**It is also discussed before:**

[Is it a good idea to learn JavaScript before learning jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668642/is-it-a-good-idea-to-learn-javascript-before-learning-jquery)

Answer (score 8):

Yes. jQuery is a Javascript library. You can only use it from Javascript code, so you need to know some Javascript in order to call it.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you do. jQuery is JavaScript library.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery **is** Javascript. So yes, to do anything usable, you need to know Javascript and understand the DOM.

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't *absolutely* need to know javascript first; with an understanding of the DOM, you could adapt jQuery code snippets to do some simple tasks on your pages without having to know the ins-and-outs of the javascript language; but knowing javascript would certainly let you get a lot more value from jQuery and would be necessary if you wanted to do anything complicated or ambitious on the page.

Comment: jQuery **is** JavaScript - it's really not possible to be just a jQuery programmer without knowing JavaScript, at least by accident

Comment: If you learn jQuery control loop control and iteration syntax, and have a basic understanding of if/then syntax, you do not need to know the ins-and-outs of javascript to accomplish simple things with jQuery on a webpage. I know what jQuery is. I use it, and I know javascript too. Read what I wrote, carefully, and you will see that there's no reason for a downvote.

Comment: I agree with the downvote (but I'm too stingy to add one myself :-))

Comment: Where, specifically, is the false statement in what I wrote? Do you guys not see that the statement was QUALIFIED? or do you not know what the  word qualified means? G*D save us from fundamentalists and dogmatists of every stripe.

Answer (score 4):

"Know" is a strong word. You don't have to learn everything about javascript, but you should be familiar with it. Debugging JQuery is a real pain without javascript knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is a library developed using javascript and to effectively work with jQuery you need to know javascript first.

If you are using jQuery you will have to deal with javascript for sure and learning jquery also becomes very easy if you have some basic under standing in javascript and [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp).

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) is a source to learn javascript basics easily.

Comment: MDC is a better source to learn JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide (of course one has to be carful about Firefox specialities)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to know basic javascript first before using jquery, In actual project most of the time jquery is used with the combination of core javascript, also if know know basics of javascript
then it is a lot easier to understand jquery because at that time you know the internal working which is hidden by jquery most of the times.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, and you should also know, what JQuery - or other frameworks - do, not just using them as a black box. Say, you should know *document.getElementById()*, even if you will never use it, because there is better way to do it in frameworks.