# Do I need to learn Javascript before learning JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it a good idea to learn JavaScript before learning jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668642/is-it-a-good-idea-to-learn-javascript-before-learning-jquery)

I want to learn html5 in order to write some games. I realized people include some JQuery code inside the game. So I head over and check JQuery and found that JQuery have some relationship with Javascript.

Should I learn Javascript before learning JQuery?

Comment: P.S. those javascript/Jquery code look like aliens to me...

Answer (score 2):

from http://jquery.com/

> jQuery is a new kind of JavaScript Library.
>
> jQuery is a fast and concise JavaScript Library that simplifies HTML document traversing, event handling, animating, and Ajax interactions for rapid web development. jQuery is designed to change the way that you write JavaScript.

So in order to use jQuery you should know JavaScript as well.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a library for the Javascript language. Yes, you have to learn it in order to use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery is a JavaScript library, so you should definitely lear JS before JQuery. It's like trying to learn Boost without C++.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery is a Javascript libary. JQuery is built on Javascript. My Javascript skills aren't high but I also use JQuery. If you learn JQuery you will learn at the same time Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a Javascript library in itself, so I **do** recommend that you study up on Javascript before jumping into jQuery. Although what jQuery is able to achieve in one line of code is far from what Javascript can achieve in even 10 lines of code, it's important to learn that foundation of something before you learn the actual structure built upon it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, jQuery is just a framework/library of javascript. You should learn javascript before leaning jQuery. When you master javascript, jQuery won't cost you one day to learn.