# Should I learn jQuery or Javascript first, or in tandem?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it a good idea to learn JavaScript before learning jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668642/is-it-a-good-idea-to-learn-javascript-before-learning-jquery)

I have been trying to teach myself Javascript recently, and I have gotten a lot of comments from people telling me that I should just teach myself jQuery.

I see uses to both - and obviously understanding Javascript lets you understand what is going on in jQuery to a greater extent. But jQuery seems easier, more intuitive and quicker to get to production level code (always useful when you're in a business environment).

Comment: isn't jQuery _written_ in JS? or maybe you mean learning 'basic DOM manipulation in JS' ?

Comment: jQuery is just an API, JavaScript is a full-blown programming language. Besides, you can't use jQuery effectively if you don't know JavaScript...

Comment: First: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: Then: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/

Answer (score 7):

I recommend to learn **javascript first**, because:

- jQuery is a javascript library so it's based on javascript
- I'm not getting along with "pure" jQuery instructions, so you'll always need to know javascript basics to do the job
- shouldn't be a big deal to learn the javascript basics

Answer (score 6):

1. JS basics
2. jQuery basics
3. Advanced methods

You should learn the basics of javascript and then move on to jQuery.
You don't need to be an expert in JS, but you should learn what JS can do for you to better understand what jQuery function are doing and why it works in a certain way.

Comment: I actually really dig this! Well done.

Answer (score 4):

Learning a framework (jQuery) without learning the language (javascript) it is based on is not the best way to go about it.

If I was starting out fresh and wanted to get productive quickly I would read Douglas Crockfords [Javascript the good parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) first. This books gives a good background on using the good parts of javascript and is the basis for many of the design ideas used in jQuery. Then I would get started with jQuery.