# Jquery or pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would a JavaScript programmer, that knows JavaScript  pretty well, write his/her code in JQuery or in pure JavaScript ?

In other words, is JQuery just for people who don't know JavaScript very well?

Lets say we are talking about creating "company presentation websites", where JavaScript mainly will be be used for animations.

Comment: jQuery is a tool. A good programmer knows when to use which tool. IMO, only if one understands JavaScript, one can use jQuery efficiently.

Comment: JS frameworks for those who don't like to waste their time. Question is floody in my opinion

Comment: How can this question be upvoted? This is a subjective question asking for opinions. It does not fit here (sorry Hakan).

Comment: @FelixKling: Because the majority of this site's users don't know what this site _is_. Neither, frankly, do they seem to care.

Comment: What if it was rephrased as "Should a professional javascript programmer learn and use jquery?"

Comment: @Matt: It's like "I know X and Y. Should I learn Z?" It's still asking for opinion.

Comment: Ok will try to not ask these opinions questions any more. Just that I am so frustrated not knowing if I should learn to write my functions i pure javascript or not. If I end up going with jquery in the end any whay there is no need to master javascript...

Comment: If you want to say it would belong more on Programmers I would agree, but I think its fair to ask which tools are actually being used in a field if you are new to the field.

Comment: @Hakan It is the first thing in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: @Hakan learning Jquery actually helped me better understand the DOM model than when I was just wrestling with pure js.  Jquery is still javascript, its not like you are choosing one or the other.

Comment: I think it should go without saying that before you learn a library (what jQuery is), you should have some understand of the programming language itself. You cannot use a library without knowing the language and the better you know the language, the better you can use the library. jQuery makes frequent use of callbacks, so of course you have to know how to define functions. That does not change with jQuery.

Comment: Have a look at this historic question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668642/is-it-a-good-idea-to-learn-javascript-before-learning-jquery

Answer (score 14, accepted):

jQuery isn't a separate programming language. It's a JavaScript library. Whether you use jQuery or not, it's still "pure JavaScript".

JavaScript is designed for both functional and object-oriented programming. And with any non-trivial application, a good programmer will likely make use of these tools to help write clean, maintainable, and efficient code.

When you group a set of functions/objects/types/etc. together that can be reused, you're creating a library—whether you give that library a name or not. Any good programmer knows to do this in order to reuse source code, provide convenience/utility functions, and avoid writing the same code over and over again for common tasks.

John Resig just happened to have created an excellent library for DOM manipulation that he's released under a generous open source license, and it's one that promotes a coding style many programmers enjoy, so it's become very popular.

I think it's safe to say that John Resig knows JavaScript pretty well, and he sure as hell uses jQuery. And if that doesn't reflect poorly on his programming abilities, then why should it reflect poorly on anyone else who uses jQuery?

Lastly, a good developer isn't defined by how much of the code in a project they wrote on their own. If you're a lonewolf hacker who likes to roll his own, that's fine. But the quality of a developer should be reflected by the quality of the end results they produce. If you build a CMS by yourself without using any pre-existing libraries or frameworks or collaborating with anyone, but it's all spaghetti code that exhibits tight coupling and violates DRY, then the fact that you wrote it all by yourself without the use of any pre-existing libraries means very little.

I think most clients would probably prefer you'd taken advantage of any off-the-shelf solutions that fit the job which could have helped complete the project in less time and produce better results.

Answer (score 6):

In Jquery you write a lot less with the same effect (usually takes a little bit slower, but it does not bother anyone) ussualy without declaring temporary var`s.
Maybe otherwise for example:

```
$('a').click (function () {/* blabla */ }).css ({/* some css here */});
```

In pure javascript that one line can be presented by:

```
var links =  document.getElementsByTagName("a") // in modern browsers = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for(var i =links.length; i--;){ 
    var l = links[i];
    l.addEventListener("click", function(){  //bla bla},true);
    l.style.someCssAtrribute = 'someValue'
   //etc
}
```

Although jQuery weighs around 100kb in return you write a lot less and more clearly

Answer (score 1):

I like to think I know javascript well, but hated using it until I learned Jquery.  With jquery I write code faster that is easier for others to read and easier to maintain.  Why wouldn't you use it?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't really help you with JavaScript as such - it helps you to work with things like DOM manipulation and events and Ajax requests. To write good software you still need a good understanding of the language but jQuery and other tools can help enormously in creating working applications.

So the answer to your question is "no, jQuery isn't just for people who don't know JavaScript".

Answer (score 0):

The strength of jQuery is that it breaks down common needs into behaviors, where jQuery does the dirty work in figuring out how to best fulfill that request considering the current browser. This makes your code consistent and concise for all browsers. Furthermore, it allows you to affect the DOM using selectors, allowing you to manipulate elements with the same intention at once rather than one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no meaning in finding the difference between Javascript and jQuery. jQuery is one of the most efficient libraries in Javascript and it makes things easier. But it is foolishness to say that jQuery is for those who don't know Javascript well. If you are an expert in Javascript you will be one of them who use jQuery efficiently. At the same time if you are a beginner in Javascript but believe that you know how to use jQuery well, I would suggest you to learn more Javascript because jQuery hides quite a lot of things from you and sometimes you might not be able to identify the mistakes you make - even a simple statement in jQuery might use a loop - so you should be careful when using jQuery. It is a matter of performance and efficiency, so if you want to write flawless code using jQuery, you should be knowing Javascript also, then only you will be able to make the most of it.