# Learn JavaScript before learning JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In 2012, when first coming into JavaScript, is it better to learn JavaScript before learning jQuery or just go straight into jQuery?

Comment: See [Is it a good idea to learn JavaScript before learning jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668642/is-it-a-good-idea-to-learn-javascript-before-learning-jquery)... still valid, though it's not a good question for SO anymore.

Comment: If your focus is in design or ux, jump straight into jQuery.  If you are a developer, grab a good javascript book (http://jsninja.com/) don't let the title fool you, the author is the creator of jQuery

Comment: both ARE JavaScript. Going one path, you will eventually end up in the other (depending on how far you will go).

Comment: How can you hope to successfully use a library without knowing the language you're writing the code in? The fact that you're making use of the jQuery library doesn't change the fact that you're writing JavaScript code. Yes, of course you should learn JavaScript before writing JavaScript code.

Answer (score 10):

Javascript is a language, jQuery is a library.

**Learn** javascript, then **use** jQuery.

Comment: +1 http://forum.jquery.com/topic/what-is-relation-between-jquery-and-javascript

Comment: +1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668642/is-it-a-good-idea-to-learn-javascript-before-learning-jquery

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend learning JavaScript first, jQuery is a tool built on top of JavaScript and at times you may want to use other tools in JavaScript (such as Handlebars.js). But learning the language underlying these tools you will have a pretty wide arsenal of tools when wanting to develop rich client side applications.

At times jQuery may not solve your problems, but by learning JavaScript you will either find the one that does or be able to create your own.

Answer (score 1):

In all times, you can't write effective code using a library without having good knowledge of language. After learning Javascript, it 'll be very easy for you to learn libraries and that fact is, there are a lot of javascript libraries. Even javascipt is famous enough for server side scripting ([Node.js](http://www.nodejs.org)).

Answer (score 1):

**A BIG YES..!!** **jQuery** is a **library/framework** which is itself written in **javascript** which is a **scripting language**. So it helps to learn javascript. You'll be better equiped to make good use of JQuery once you've a little know how of JavaScript.

Comment: obviously first **javascript** then **jquery**

Answer (score 1):

If you are a programmer/developer, there is no question that you should learn javascript before jQuery.

If you only "learn jQuery" (which is impossible anyway if you don't learn javascript), you cannot ever have any understanding of what the hell you are doing.

However, if you learn javascript, you won't have much trouble learning jQuery since it's just a bunch of javascript.

If you are a designer, you probably don't need all that and can just stick to copypasting jQuery snippets/plugin configurations.

Answer (score -4):

I didn't learn javascript, I learned only jquery.

```
<script scr="jquery.min.js">
///
</script>
```

It works actually. jquery already wraps up all functions available in old javascript, from CSS to DOM, and more. To me, it is the jquery that defines me, not the javascript.

What can be done with JS can be achieved easily with jquery because jquery is written in js and offers users a different coding style to make up for what is noisy, lengthy and obviously error-prone in js.

Comment: "What can be done with JS can be achieved easily with jquery" ... yeah, it's advice like this that spawns those inane questions like "how do I write a function in jQuery?"

Comment: The problem is that not everything can be solved in jQuery and sometimes you don't even need jQuery (especially when it's quite a large include).