# Is jquery a dynamic redefinition of javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, node.js

[Learn JavaScript before learning JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071308/learn-javascript-before-learning-jquery/10071626#10071626)

I have read that thread and I still don't find any points convincing me that Javascript is a must-learn-before-jquery thing.

I think jquery is far more than just a javascript library, I would like to call it a redefinition of the dynamic language, the new javascript instead. The library writers clearly made the greatest hit here to change old JavaScript's face almost completely.
Javascript and Jquery are co-existing because Jquery is the javascript library and the fact that people support learning JS first before jquery is likely because they've been client side coders long before the jquery was out, WHICH CURRENTLY EASES THEIR INVESTIGATIONS INTO THE LANGUAGE FAR BETTER, psychologically, they certainly then say "Oh yes, procedural methodologies work greater".

For points concerning writing a function call via mouse/keyboard events, I still agree that javascript structures are preserved and need learning. But does this really make a big difference whether or not learning jquery first should be more beneficial at all ?
Ex:

```
function something()
{
   //jquery code
}
////
<input type="..." onclick="something();"/>
```

Advice and corrections are required. Thank you so very much.

Comment: SO is not your blog. What does it mean to "learn jquery BEFORE javascript"? That makes no sense.

Comment: People always seem to forget that JavaScript !== the DOM...

Comment: *"I think jquery is far more than just a javascript library..."* No, it's just a library.

Answer (score 4):

There are many reasons why its important to learn the native JavaScript, in addition to the jQuery Library:

- jQuery is written in JavaScript, so if you ever run into a jQuery bug, or need to patch it, you will need to know the JavaScript
- if you ever want to use jQuery efficiently, in many cases it's helpful to read the underlying JavaScript
- it isn't guaranteed that jQuery will always be the best Library (something like Scriptaculous may one day surpass it), thus you shouldn't be library-dependent
- in many cases you still need to run JavaScript inside of a jQuery function
- jQuery may make many things simpler (accessing DOM elements), but in many cases it isn't required

Comment: to add to that, jQuery provides a "normalized" platform to work on the browser. without jQuery, good luck with all the browser quirks!