# When starting from scratch: Javascript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it a good idea to learn JavaScript before learning jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668642/is-it-a-good-idea-to-learn-javascript-before-learning-jquery)

I'm new to javascript in general.  I can write basic functions that do basic things and that's just great.  I started to dabble in JQuery recently because, well, its trendy and does cool things.  For example I used their validation plugin on a site, saved me loads of time.  Thing is I'm just depending on pre-written scripts to get the job done.  I'd like to learn more so I can write my own custom solutions as problems arise.  So my question is which is better to build a foundation on, Javascript or JQuery.  I know JQuery is essentially a Javascript object with lots of cool methods so would it be better to learn the ropes on plain old Javascript because I'll be more "well rounded".  Or should I skip the foreplay and stick with the trending hip JQuery?

Comment: `jQuery` is based on `javascript`. They're languages on different abstraction levels.

Comment: As the others say, jQuery (framework) builds on top of JavaScript (language) hence it does not make sense to "learn" jQuery first. You need a solid understanding of the underlying language before using jQuery starts making sense.

Comment: @kev jQuery is most definitely not a "language".  It is a library.

Comment: This is like asking: "When starting from scratch: cooking or oil?" Javascript is the big thing, jQuery is one tiny optional thing that can help in many situations.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is JavaScript. Build a foundation in JavaScript.

Once you know the ins and outs of vanilla JavaScript, working with jQuery will make much more sense and you'll be able to fix things and build your own solutions when problems arise.

Answer (score 1):

Both.

If you plan to do a good bit of JavaScript development then you'll want to learn JavaScript as a foundation.  You'll want to know how the language works, what its design strengths and weaknesses are, etc.  You don't necessarily need to be able to write your own replacement for jQuery, but it's good to know the tools that you're using.

jQuery, as you know, is a framework.  It's a tool made by experts to perform common tasks in a clean and maintainable way.  Framework are also good to know.  You want to understand the foundations on which they're build, but you also want to have useful tools in your toolbelt to get work done effectively.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should learn first basic javascript, especially focusing on the good and bad practices, because it's easy to write awful jQuery code if you're not aware of what you're doing.

E.g. in jQuery, DOM manipulation is pretty straightforward and easy but if you don't know that every manipulation comes with a cost in terms of performance your code will work anyway but it won't be definitively a good and reusable code (and in jQuery reusability matters a lot since in the long distance you're supposed to organize your code in plugins)

So spend your time especially on the language, try to apply some widely used [good practices](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml) and when you start feeling a bit confident with them try jQuery

Answer (score 1):

If you have spare time and are focused more on learning best practices then I would suggest starting with plain, old JavaScript without any libraries like jQuery. If you start with JavaScript, then you will learn the actual language, you'll be able to differentiate between what is JavaScript and what is jQuery, and (perhaps the most important point in my opinion ) eventually you will run into many of the cross-browser JavaScript issues that have plagued web developers over the years. This will give you a great picture of the overall scene and will make you a better developer.

On the other hand, if you're working on a timeline or are working on something that you eventually want to release and maintain, you should go with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

**Start with Javascript!** Do not learn Javascript by using jQuery, because it's just a library (albeit a very popular one). If you don't start with learning vanilla Javascript, you'll never learn how to program in it correctly. Once you learn Javascript, jQuery will come by itself. This doesn't work the other way around, though; if you learn jQuery, Javascript will still be a big mystery to you.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to note is that jQuery is javaScript. It is not a separate language or any other type of magic, it's just a library you can use to make some common javaScript patterns less painful.

So the real question here would be, should you use jQuery or just stick to native js? The answer to this question depends mostly on your environment. If you are writing a personal web page, I would definitely use jQuery. If you are working in a corporate environment, there are probably some hoops you need jump through in order to use jQuery freely.

Comment: No no no. You need to learn Javascript (at least the very basics of it) first before jumping straight into jQuery!

Comment: @ElliotBonneville i am speaking from a perspective of building a software product, not education.

Comment: Granted, but you are much more likely to screw up if you don't know what you're doing with Javascript (not to mention the entire process would be much more laborious). I'd say in this case it's more important to start with Javascript than jQuery than if we were talking about education, because the stakes are generally higher.

Comment: You also shouldn't use jQuery as the default library that fixes your problems, there are many good and far better alternatives

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend jQuery to start.  It's much easier and much more cross browser.  When you need to use straight Javascript, you will learn it.  AJAX, for instance, is MUCH easier with jQuery and I wouldn't ever recommend that someone try to implement their own solution when jQuery has already done most of the work for you.  It's just a waste of time.  There are certain things that you will need Javascript for, but as you find them - that's when you should learn them.